# Currency format input values in ZF2 Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

When I save a form I can automatically format the value with an inputfilter. Is this also possible when I hydrate a form to edit the object?

So i've got a Doctrine object. In this object i've got a currency value like "5.95" But i want to show it in the text input as "5,95"

Comment: Personally I would create a Hydrator model specifically for this purpose (or combined purposes obviously). You'll generally want your ORM to 'speak the truth' about a field value, so I would avoid changing it immediately in the entity getter.

Comment: What do I have to search for to create a Hydrator model for this purpose? I'm a zend beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a code example (warning; I have not tested it!) of how a Hydrator would work, assuming that `ORM\Entity\SomeTable` is your Doctrine entity. We will also assume for this example sake, that all entities implement the `ORM\Entity\EntityInterface`.

What you first want to do, is create a new interface called `ORM\Hydrator\HydratorInterface`, that will be used to hydrate the entity. That interface will then be used by any other hydrator, to make sure they are all the same and can be identified more easily.

```
<?php

namespace ORM\Hydrator;

/**
 * HydratorInterface provides a template to functionality which
 * every hydrator needs to implement.
 */
interface HydratorInterface
{
    /**
     * Inflates an entity with the given array.
     *
     * @param \ArrayAccess $data
     * @return \ORM\Entity\EntityInterface
     */
    public static function inflate(array $data, \ORM\Entity\EntityInterface $entity = null);

    /**
     * Deflates an entity and returns an array of data.
     *
     * @param \ORM\Entity\EntityInterface $entity
     * @return array
     */
    public static function deflate(\ORM\Entity\EntityInterface $entity);
}
```

In the interface we define the `inflate()` method, that needs data to *inflate* a Doctrine object for you. The `deflate()` method here will retrieve properties from your entity and return a normal array. This is where your question will be answered.

For the sake of this example we will skip the `inflate()` method for now, as that is the opposite of your question, however I am more than happy to elaborate on the subject.

Now we will create the hydrator object, that will implement the interface, and where all the *magic* happens.

```
<?php

namespace ORM\Hydrator;

use HydratorInterface;

class SomeTable implements HydratorInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function inflate(array $data, \ORM\Entity\EntityInterface $entity = null)
    {
        // We'll leave this method for now.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function deflate(\ORM\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
    {
        // First you'll want to check if the entity provided, is also the 
        // one we expect it to be
        if (!($entity instanceof \ORM\Entity\SomeTable)) {
            // Unfortunately not, let's get it out
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                "Expected instance of %s, received %s.",
                'ORM\Entity\SomeTable',
                get_class($entity)
            ));
        }

        // And now, the simple deflation begins
        return array(
            // Format the currency to Dutch decimal points
            'myAmount' => number_format($entity->getMyAmount(), 2, ',', '.')
        );
    }
}
```

Now to use it just do the following:

```
// Assuming $entity is your entity
$deflatedEntity = \ORM\Hydrator\SomeTable::deflate($entity);
```

As you can see this implementation is hilariously simple, but it saves a lot of complexity in your code. This example is obviously not perfect, but it is a good start.

Comment: Allright, where do I use `$deflatedEntity = \ORM\Hydrator\SomeTable::deflate($entity);`?